# How to input quarterly data in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have panel of quarterly data which looks like this:

```
x <- c("Q1 2013","Q2 2013", "Q3 2013", "Q4 2013")
```

How can I be able to properly input this data into r as quarterly time series date so I would be able to perform analysis on it?

I tried to use yearqtr from zoo package but all I receive is NA.

```
as.Date(as.yearqtr(x, format = "Q%q /%yyyy"))
```

This could be because of the space between Q1 and 2013, I'm open to change my format if I have to but I'm not even sure what format would work in R. Should I change my columns to 1.2013, 2.2013, ... or this would also not be recognized as a date format by R? And how am I gonna be able to change them when I have a repeated sample of quarterly date in this format: Q1 2013, etc.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(zoo::as.yearqtr(x, format = "Q%q %Y"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
as.yearqtr(format(x), "Q%q %Y")
```

This is the output:

```
# [1] "2013 Q1" "2013 Q2" "2013 Q3" "2013 Q4"
```

You can make it as dates meanwhile:

```
as.Date(as.yearqtr(format(x), "Q%q %Y"))
```

And the output would be:

```
# [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-04-01" "2013-07-01" "2013-10-01"
```